# D3 Tree Search using Input - Search on Lower Case

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a D3 tree search using an input.  This works well when typing the right case, but I need to have it working as lower case (the node names typically have camel case).

I have the following search function working with a search input:

```
  function searchTree( d ) {
                if ( d.children )
                    d.children.forEach( searchTree );
                else if ( d._children )
                    d._children.forEach( searchTree );
                var searchFieldValue = eval( searchField );
                if ( searchFieldValue && searchFieldValue.match( searchText ) ) {
                    // Walk parent chain
                    var ancestors = [];
                    var parent = d;
                    while ( typeof ( parent ) !== "undefined" ) {
                        ancestors.push( parent );
                        //console.log(parent);
                        parent.class = "found";
                        parent = parent.parent;
                    }
                    //console.log(ancestors);
                }
            }
```

This works if typing the correct case for `d.name`, but does not match when the case is different.  So I need to change it to search on lower case when searching from the input.

How can I change the search function to obtain a match on lowercase?

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nf9xc4a5/)

Comment: lowercase both the string to be searched and string in which it is searched

Comment: You can use `searchFieldValue.toLowerCase().match( searchText.toLowerCase() )` to match strings. This lowercases both the text and matches them.
Updated the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/2o4qp08z/1/)

Comment: Lone Ranger..Thanks, want to put that into an answer?

Comment: yeah sure, writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
searchFieldValue.toLowerCase().match( searchText.toLowerCase() )
```

to match strings. This lowercases both the text and matches them.

Here is the link to the Fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/2o4qp08z/1/)